# Error en paypal (click_initiate_payment_reject error when clicking to paypal)

Tags: javascript, paypal

Estoy desarrollando una app que necesita un sistema de subscriciones con paypal como pasarela de pagos.
Hasta ayer me funcionaba perfecto en sandbox, activaba y desactivaba subscriciones pero hoy comenzo a funcionar mal, me canse de buscar soluciones en paypal, la mesa de ayuda es nula y los foros de esta plataforma solo tiene preguntas y ni una respuesta.

El error aparece cuando hago click en el boton "smart" de paypal, la teoria es que tiene que abrir una ventana tipo "popup" para realizar el pago correspondiente, pero abre una fraccion de segundo y se cierra.El error que me tira la consola es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe de todo, cree una aplicacion nueva, con usuarios nuevos, planes nuevos, y lo mismo me tira ese error.

Alguien tendra una idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Pues leyendo el error de tu captura veo que pone "TOKEN FAILURE"... que no sea eso, que te haya expirado el TOKEN que te dieron para pruebas y lo tengas que renovar o algo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya probe eso, me cree hasta una cuenta nueva con un sandbox nuevo, y sigue el mismo error. Es de ellos me parece.

Comment: y si le das al enlace que aparece junto a ese error que dice "Mostras más" no te da una información más detallada de lo que falla en ese TOKEN?

Comment: Me da un texto gigantesco, pero no detalla nada, lei todo para ver si me daba alguna pista, pero no fue el caso.

Comment: Pues ni idea, te tocará intentar mediar con ellos a ver que ocurre.  O esperar que alguien de por aquí realmente lo sepa, que lo siento pero no es mi caso. Suerte!